# How to show JSON with an array inside in Angular 2?

Tags: arrays, json, angular

After solve lot of problems to make my app work, http headers and more... now it's working!

Now, when I try to show the data into my app I have a little problem - ask.

I have this schema:

```
export class Morosos {
idlor:  String;  comunidad: String; vivienda: String;  demandado:   String;  importe:   String;  datos: [{ fecha: String, dato: String }];  date: { type: Date };}
```

And I have this on .html component:

```
<tr *ngFor="let p of results; let i=index">
  <td>{{p.idlor}}</td>
  <td>{{p.comunidad}}</td>
  <td>{{p.vivienda}}</td>
  <td>{{p.demandado}}</td>
  <td>{{p.importe}}</td>
  <td>{{p.datos | json}} </td>
  <td>{{p.date}}</td>
</tr>
```

And i got this:

> IDLOR Comunidad   Vivienda    Demandado   Importe Datos   Fecha
>   LOR01/16  XXX XXX XXX     XXXX    [ { "fecha": "08/03/2017", "dato": "Pagado
>   Ejecucion" }, { "fecha": "27/07/2016", "dato": "Carta enviada" }
>   ] 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z

As you can see I have a JSON on "Datos" which is an array, now my dude is how to put it into a `<tr><td>` too.

Thanks :)

Comment: Could you include your result as your actual JSON, now it really doesn't make sense ;)

Comment: {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58c81ba0fb02f3066e2af169"
    },
    "idlor": "LOR01/16",
    "comunidad": "x",
    "vivienda": "x",
    "demandado": "x",
    "importe": "x",
    "datos": [
        {
            "fecha": "08/03/2017",
            "dato": "Pagado Ejecucion"
        },
        {
            "fecha": "27/07/2016",
            "dato": "Carta enviada"
        }
    ],
    "date": {
        "$date": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one mre ngFor in the td with ul tag.

```html
<td>
  <ul *ngFor="let p of p.datos">
    <li>{{p}}</li>
   </ul>
</td>
```

Comment: Where you put "let p" is "let d" but it works fine. Thanks!